# How to import Bokeh palettes

Tags: python, bokeh

How to use the [D3 Palettes](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/reference/palettes.html#d3-palettes) in Bokeh?
I tried importing this way but I get an unresolved reference error message

```
from bokeh.palettes import Category20
```

Bokeh version:

```
print bokeh.__version__

0.11.1
```

Comment: for question improvement can you added the error text. (End of Review).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In bokeh 0.11.1 the Category20 palette does not exist

It's implemented in the 0.12.4 (the latest one), and works perfectly

```
from bokeh.palettes import Category20
```

Let's try to update it if you can.

Comment: I've just upgraded to 0.12.4. But issue this persist: `from bokeh.palettes import Category20` I get `unresolved reference`

Comment: It's very strange, I'm using python 3.5.3 under a conda environment and I've no problems

Comment: I'm using Anaconda python 2.7. Could this be related: https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/5813  by the way, I'm using pycharm

Comment: I created a python 2.7 env and the Category20 palette does not exist. So .... it's a 2.7 version issue i think

Comment: Okay, thanks for narrowing it down to the python version..thanks!

Answer (score 5):

```
Category20:
{3: ['#1f77b4', '#aec7e8', '#ff7f0e'],
 4: ['#1f77b4', '#aec7e8', '#ff7f0e', '#ffbb78'],
 5: ['#1f77b4', '#aec7e8', '#ff7f0e', '#ffbb78', '#2ca02c'],
 6: ['#1f77b4', '#aec7e8', '#ff7f0e', '#ffbb78', '#2ca02c', '#98df8a'],
 7: ['#1f77b4',.... ]
.
.
20: []
```

So best way to use is:

```
Category20[20][0]
```

Answer (score 1):

All answers so far refer to the pre-built palettes available as module *attributes*, but it may help others to note that there are also *functions* that can be used to generate palettes in Bokeh.

First, note that each of the module attribute palettes is a dictionary of tuples, each indexed by length n and containing a list of hex color codes of that length. e.g., I'll use `Colorblind` palette, because it's smaller:

```
>>> from bokeh.palettes import Colorblind
>>> Colorblind
{3: ('#0072B2', '#E69F00', '#F0E442'), 4: ('#0072B2', '#E69F00', '#F0E442', '#009E73'), 5: ('#0072B2', '#E69F00', '#F0E442', '#009E73', '#56B4E9'), 6: ('#0072B2', '#E69F00', '#F0E442', '#009E73', '#56B4E9', '#D55E00'), 7: ('#0072B2', '#E69F00', '#F0E442', '#009E73', '#56B4E9', '#D55E00', '#CC79A7'), 8: ('#0072B2', '#E69F00', '#F0E442', '#009E73', '#56B4E9', '#D55E00', '#CC79A7', '#000000')}`
```

Then the Colorblind palette of length-3 is accessed as:

```
>>> Colorblind[3]
('#0072B2', '#E69F00', '#F0E442')
```

There are also large 256 color palettes (e.g., `Cividis256`), which are also just tuples of 256 hex color codes.

But in addition to accessing palettes as *attributes*, the `bokeh.palettes` module also offers *functions* that can generate lists of colors of arbitrary size from the special larger palettes. Several of these large palettes and functions are described in the [docs](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/reference/palettes.html?highlight=palette#module-bokeh.palettes), e.g., to generate a palette of length 6 from the `Cividis256` palette, the built-in `cividis` function can be used:

```
>>> from bokeh.palettes import cividis
>>> cividis(6)
('#00204C', '#31446B', '#666870', '#958F78', '#CAB969', '#FFE945')
```

Note also that some larger palettes available are not in the current (2.2.3) version of the docs (e.g. `Reds256`), but they can also be used with the `linear_palette` function to generate the same sort of thing, e.g., a palette of 20 reds:

```
>>> from bokeh.palettes import Reds256, linear_palette
>>> linear_palette(Reds256, 20)
('#67000d', '#800610', '#9a0c14', '#af1117', '#be151a', '#cf1c1f', '#dd2a25', '#ec382b', '#f34c37', '#f85f43', '#fb7252', '#fc8262', '#fc9474', '#fca588', '#fcb69b', '#fdc6b0', '#fdd5c4', '#fee3d7', '#ffece3', '#fff5f0')
```

The `diverging_palette` function is also worth checking out.

Answer (score 0):

For those searching for information on bokeh palettes, the [docs](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/reference/palettes.html?highlight=palette#module-bokeh.palettes) now have an excellent expanded list of available palettes.

Bokeh 2.2.3 includes D3 palettes 10, 20, 20b, 20c

For example, you can specify the D3 palette category and then specify as a string 'Category20b' group as the first index and then specify as an integer the number of colors in the group as the second index.

```
>> d3['Category20b'][4]
('#393b79', '#5254a3', '#6b6ecf', '#9c9ede')
```

If you can't find the palette you like, create your own using a python list of (hex) RGB color strings.

```
('#084594', '#2171b5', '#4292c6', '#6baed6', '#9ecae1', '#c6dbef', '#deebf7', '#f7fbff')
```